# How to know if a DateTime is Between two Dates in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an application and a database created by Entity Framework Core, I have an entity called `ListUsers` with this property:

```
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

I have another class with properties to do a filter, this is my filter class:

```
 public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
 public DateTime? InitDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

I have another properties to do the filter, with other properties works fine but when I send the DateTime properties it does not work, this is my Linq query to do the filter:

```
var result = await _context.ListUsers
                           .Include(lu => lu.List)
                           .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                           .Where(lu => lu.CreationDate.Date >= filter.InitDate
                                        && lu.CreationDate.Date <= filter.EndDate
                                        && lu.Country == filter.Country
                                        && lu.City == filter.City
                                        && lu.Locality == filter.Locality
                                        && lu.Neighborhood == filter.Neighborhood
                                        && lu.List.Id == filter.ListId)
                           .ToListAsync();
return result;
```

in my DB there are two registers with this date: "2021-08-01 17:47:12.8614628" but "result" always is empty, I'm sending this json from Postman:

```
{
   "listId": "090A5C4D-04AB-434E-A0EF-C579B6D1D0C8",  
   "initDate": "2021-08-01",
   "endDate": "2021-08-12",
   "neighborhood": "portsland"
}
```

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You filter on Country, City and Locality, but the JSON does not contain any of them, so the filtering happens on `null` values, which is most likely the reason why you get no results.

You need to either provide all values in the JSON, or change the filtering to do nothing for `null` values.

Example filter:

```
&& (filter.Country == null || lu.Country == filter.Country)
```

Comment: it worked perfect, thanks bro ;)

Comment: or build your query in pieces; `if (filter.Country != null) query = query.Where(lu => lu.Country == filter.Country);`